# Hide div when clicking outside of it doesn't work on iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad

I have the following code:

```
$(document).on('click touch', function(e) {
    var nav    = $(e.target).closest('.nav-js-trigger');
    var hidden = $(e.target).closest('.show-nav')

    if ( nav.length > 0 ) {
        $('.show-nav').not( nav.next().toggleClass('show-nav') ).removeClass('show-nav');
    } else if ( hidden.length === 0 ) {
        $('.show-nav').removeClass('show-nav');
    }
});
```

It hides the menu div if user clicks outside of it. To test this:

1. Click on Menu link.
2. Click outside of the yellow div.

The div should get hidden.

The problem is that **this does not work on iPad**. Why?

Here is a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/q6qcknrb/2/).

I have added `click touch` and also tried `touchend` and `touchstart`.

Comment: Given the complexity of this question, I will bounty this 50 points when eligible.

Comment: Have you also tried putting the listener on `document.documentElement`, `document.body` and/or `window`? And I suggest using `touchend` for this. Also try vanilla Javascript [as suggested by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html): `document.documentElement.addEventListener("touchend", function(e){ ... }, false);`

Answer (score 2):

Got a message:

> Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes

So I'll post it as an answer instead.

- I suggest using `touchend` in your tests, the `touch` event does not exist. Maybe your tests failed because of browser cache?
- Have you also tried putting the listener on `document.documentElement`, `document.body` and/or `window`?
- Try vanilla JavaScript [like suggested by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html):

  ```
  document.documentElement.addEventListener("touchend", function(e){ alert('hello world'); }, false);
  ```

---

[Fiddle with `document.documentElement` and `touchend`](https://jsfiddle.net/1vcmun28/)

Comment: Interesting. Can you kindly update the fiddle so that I can test this suggestion on iPad: http://jsfiddle.net/q6qcknrb/2/

Comment: I added a fiddle that should work on on iPad in theory. If that doesn't work you could also try using jQuery 1.x instead of 2.x: https://jsfiddle.net/mdyr7x4e/